# Spring endpoint for downloading file succeeds (200), but calls the /error endpoint (406)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

One of Spring servers has an endpoint for downloading files. This server is a gateway, so it calls another server to fetch the file. The internal call succeeds, and the file content is returned to the gateway server.

In order to preserve the response headers from the internal call, the gateway creates a `ResponseEntity` object. These headers include the `content-type`, `content-length`, and `content-disposition`.

The issue is that when the gateway endpoint returns, the request is somehow redirected to the `/error` endpoint, which returns with status code 406.

This is the endpoint code:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/download", produces = APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK, reason = "Success")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadAttachment(
    @RequestParam String name,
    @RequestParam String referenceId)
{
    return internalService.downloadFile(referenceId, name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the issue. The `@ResponseStatus` annotation overrides the custom `ResponseEntity`. In fact, this is actually documented in the annotation's Javadoc:

```
The status code is applied to the HTTP response when the handler
method is invoked and overrides status information set by other means,
like {@code ResponseEntity} or {@code "redirect:"}.
```

I hope this will help others who accidentally use both `ResponseEntity` and `@ResponseStatus` on the same endpoint.

Comment: You found that in the same second when you added the query.

Comment: Yes, this is called answering your own question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).